# Minecraft launcher Loading Versions Falure

Tags: java, minecraft

Hiya I am using the default Minecraft launcher.exe version 1.6.70. I log in but the launcher gets stuck at loading versions. I am on windows 10 Home Version 1607 and running Java 1.8.0_111 both 32 and 64bit. I am included a error log and a screeshot.

Steps: I have removed java and updated it. I removed the default .Minecraft folder and let it remake it. I have allowed java and minecraft through the windows firewall. I had disconnected the machine from the network and restarted the router and modem but nothing so far has worked.

Thanks for your time.

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/18gwnljzu93o6s4/Error%201.PNG?dl=0

Error log: http://pastebin.com/UKK5tMXG

Answer (score 0):

1. uninstall then reinstall minecraft
2. if your 32 bit, remove the 64 bit java. vise versa
3. Make sure all of your variables for java are correct

Comment: uninstalled minecraft and removed 32bit java and set variables as follows. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3fa9q0y6un4lhwv/Environment%20Variables.PNG?dl=0 also here is a hijackthis log. https://www.dropbox.com/s/pr0swwldz1zu6ur/hijackthis.log?dl=0

Comment: No fix. Anything else?